# How to make a clickable Listview data from mysql in asynctask

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am developing a simple application which retrieves data from MySQL database through AsyncTask.

I have done retrieveing the data in listview, but still cannot make the listview clickable. I am new in using AsyncTask, makes me don't know how to make the listview clickable. I tried to give `OnItemClickListener()` for my `ListView` inside `onPostExecute()` method, but still no result.
I have searched for a related topic here but didn't find any.

Here I show codes I've written:

```
public class MyClass extends ListActivity {

protected TextView title;
protected ImageView icon;

static String the_name = "name";
static String the_location = "location";
JSONArray str_json = null;
public String url;

ListView listData;

private ProgressDialog pDialog;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data_map = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.alldata);
    getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
            R.layout.window_header);
    title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.title);
    icon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.icon);

    this.title.setText("All Data");
    this.icon.setImageResource(R.drawable.alldata);

    Connection conn = new Connection();
    url = conn.connectData();
    new GetMyData().execute();  

}

class GetMyData extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyData.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Data" + "\r\n" + "Please Wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

        String link_url = url + "serverandroid2.php";
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJson(link_url);

        try {
            str_json = json.getJSONArray("mydata");

            for (int i = 0; i < str_json.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject ar = str_json.getJSONObject(i);

                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                String name= ar.getString("name");
                String location= ar.getString("region") + " | "
                        + ar.getString("city");

                map.put(the_name, name);
                map.put(the_location, location);

                data_map.add(map);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        pDialog.dismiss();          
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyClass.this, data_map, R.layout.list_row, new String[] {
                                the_name, the_location }, new int[] {
                                R.id.tvname,
                                R.id.tvlocation });
                setListAdapter(adapter);
            }

        });
        listData = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        listData.setClickable(true);

        listData.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent,
                    View viewRow, int position, long id) {

                try{
                    Intent viewDetail = null;
                    JSONObject jsonChildExtra = str_json.getJSONObject(position);
                    String nameEx = jsonChildExtra
                            .optString("name");
                    String locationEx = jsonChildExtra
                            .optString("location");
                    String regionEx = jsonChildExtra
                            .optString("region");

                    viewDetail = new Intent(MyClass.this,
                            NextClass.class);
                    viewDetail.putExtra("name",
                            nameEx);
                    viewDetail.putExtra("location",
                            locationEx);
                    viewDetail.putExtra("region", regionEx);
                    startActivity(viewDetail);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }
        });


    }
}
}
```

Class `Connection` up there contains a method with the URL inside it. I call it by making an object of it named `conn`.

I have two layout up there, the first one contains the `listView` with Id `list`, and the other one contains `textviews` where I will put the data with Id `tvName` and `tvLocation`.

Here is my layout XML codes for the `ListView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/layout_border" >

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dip"
            android:background="@drawable/labeldetail_background" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip"
                android:paddingTop="10dip"
                android:text="All Data"
                android:textColor="#000000" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@android:id/list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/labeldetail_background" >
            </ListView>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

And here is XML codes for the `TextView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_list"
android:orientation="horizontal">  
<LinearLayout        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvName"
        android:text="Data Not Found"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:paddingBottom="2dip" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvLocation"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="10sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Could you please hand me sample of code or just pseudo code of how to solve it.
Thanks.

Comment: It is not a good idea to have a Listview inside a Scrollview since both are scrollable... Not sure if that is the case but it might be one of your problems, since the touch might not be going to the component you want.

Comment: Also all the code you have in the onPostExecute method you can have in onCreate of MyClass. In onPostExecute you only need to set the data to the list adapter and call listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged().

Comment: @Mikel O yes, I've just noticed it. The scrollview is marked yellow in my xml file.But I don't think it is the problem in this case. 

I have tried that, I put that code (onItemClickListener and below) inside onCreate method, but shows nothing too. I'll give it another try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

create listviews inside of onPostExecute method is not the best way to do it, but if you really need that behavior, try the runOnUI() thread to add the event listener at the proper application thread. regards

Comment: I will try to explore it. Anyway, is there any other way to call and give listview an onClickItemListener() beside that? If there is, I will love to see an advice